# Monopole problem

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, magnetic-monopoles

Original question: So theory predicts that the monople number density at time of GUT was $10^{82}$ per cubic meter, due to inflation it's diluted and today it's about $10^{-16}$ per cubic Mpc.

This is lower only by 2 orders of magnitude than today's photon number density (~$10^8$ per cubic meter), but still much higher than today's baryon number density. And even back at GUT, the monople number density was higher than baryon number density, and they both will dilute as $1/a^3$.

So how come today we see baryons everywhere, but the monopole is hard to detect because of its "low number density" due to inflation?

Update:
I made a mistake in my comparison calculation for today. Also, while trying to extrapolate today's baryon and matter energy density back to GUT for a comparison at that time, I used the ratio between today's temperature and GUT temperature since $T \propto 1/a$, but I failed to realize the temperature after the inflation went back to before the inflation, but $a$ has changed a lot, so by using temperature ratio directly to scale back will not work.

Comment: (a) Do you have a source for the monopole density before and after inflation? Surely those numbers are model dependent? (b) According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), the lack of magnetic monopole detections "places an upper limit on the number of monopoles of about one monopole per $10^{29}$ nucleons." So either the model you are referring to is ruled out, or it's some other kind of weakly interacting monopole that wouldn't be detected by the searches described on wikipedia.

Comment: The source is a textbook, but I just realized I made a mistake in my calculation. Will update the original post. Thanks.

Comment: [So... $10^{-16} {\rm Mpc}^{-3} = 3 \times 10^{-84}\ {\rm m}^{-3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%28-16%29+%2F+megaparsec%5E3+)... does that resolve your question?

Comment: Yeah that's definitely part of the problem. But the other mistake was when extrapolating backwards, which further convinced me of the first mistake. I've updated the post.

Comment: @Andrew, actually I'm confused again. Were there matter particles and photons before inflation? If so they got super-diluted during inflation, but then at the end of inflation the "re-heating" created a bunch of new matter particles and photons so that their density went back to pre-inflation time? Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: The idea would be that the inflaton field produced ordinary matter and radiation at the end of inflation, "somehow." There are various mechanisms that have been proposed for this process, such as reheating and preheating, and many (many) models that attempt to implement these mechanisms. I'm not an expert on the monopole problem, but as far as I understand, inflation only helps resolve the monopole problem if the phase transition that created the monopoles happened before inflation. (FWIW I've always considered the monopole problem more model-dependent than the horizon and curvature problems).

Comment: @Andrew, I see. What you said does make a lot of sense. What made me think there were already particles before the inflation was this passage from the Barbra Ryden cosmology textbook:

Comment: "Not only is inflation very effective at driving down the number density of magnetic monopoles, /it is also effective at driving down the number density of every other type of particle, including photons/. The chilly post-inflationary period didn’t last though. As the energy density associated with the inflaton field was converted to relativistic particles such as photons, the temperature of the universe was restored to its pre-inflationary value Ti." --- It says there were particles before the inflation. Was this statement outdated? Thank you.

Comment: I think the honest answer is that we don't know what happened before inflation. (We don't even know that inflation happened!) Many people are agnostic about it (especially since it is hard to imagine how you'd probe the pre inflation era observationally), although there are some models.

Comment: @Andrew, ha thanks for the honest answer. I get it. I'm just trying to figure out how much "inflation" if happened would mess up calculations we've been taught without it, such as number density back to early times, horizon distance, proper distance calculation etc. Shouldn't these all be revised to include the inflation period?  

Specifically, wouldn't the whole discussion of CMB larger than horizon scale feature be out of the window if the horizon includes the whole sky? But no textbook talks about it. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/740573/inflation-and-cmb-power-spectrum